# Error : unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a script to export CSV data to mysql table.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /data/NEW

for f in User*
do
        mysql --user="root" --password="user@123" -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/"$f"' ignore into table new.table2 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (table_date, table_name, table_count);"

done
```

But I am getting following errors. But I could not find where I have messed this.

```
test.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
test.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can someone show me where to improve?

Comment: Why do you end the string before `$f`? Variables are expanded inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping double quotes as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /data/NEW
for f in User*
do
        mysql --user="root" --password="user@123" -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/$f' ignore into table new.table2 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\n' (table_date, table_name, table_count);"

done
```

Comment: That will put literal double quotes in the filename.

Comment: You're right about the double quote in `enclosed by`, but not the ones around `$f`. Those double quotes aren't even needed in the first place.